# can you help me solve a Javascript code please: Try printing stars in the following format for n rows. * ** *** **** for n times

Tags: javascript

```
Try printing stars in the following format for n rows.
```

*

**

---

---

for n times

Comment: Could you show us what you tried?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on code golf or similar.

Answer (score 2):

```
let n = 4;

for (let i = 0; n >= i; i++) {
    console.log('*'.repeat(i))
}
```

Something like this should help you. Please ensure to read contribution guidelines and maybe show what you've tried. This is a simple implementation which should help you.

Good luck!

Comment: I think we want to repeat the `*` i times, so we'd need `console.log('*'.repeat(i))`

Comment: Good catch! Adjust as needed.

Comment: thank you but no it shows a serie of ***** :/

Comment: Wiwi, I just checked it in console to ensure. This resolves your issue. I'm sorry you're having issues, but it must be something on your end.